# How to do OCR with Google's AutoML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl

I want to do OCR and I know that Cloud Vision API supports it. But I'm interested in making my custom model for it and wish to use AutoML for the same. But I couldn't find anything related to OCR using AutoML. Is it possible to do OCR using AutoML? How do we go about this? I know this is a very open-ended question, but I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do OCR from AutoML. Your options are to use the Cloud Vision API to do OCR and then apply your own algorithms to put the detected letters together in a certain way, or to start from scratch and train your own OCR model (not recommended).

Comment: basically you are saying "Google Vision OCR is far better than any open source or other software out there maybe with the exception of AWS or Azure's offerings?"  I tried GCP Vision API along with about 10 open source I found on GitHub and do believe the above statement but want to confirm.

Comment: @mLstudent33 I do think that is true, but in my answer I am saying that because training your own OCR model when one that works really well is already available is generally a waste of effort when you could put it on other tasks that haven't been done already or are unique to you. I don't think people should roll their own OCR or translate when there are huge teams working on these tasks already and your chances of outperforming them are quite low.

Answer (score 3):

[AutoML Natural Language](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare) can perform OCR on PDFs; however, this is just a step because is intended for creating your on models on text classification, entity extraction or sentiment analysis.

If you goal is just to perform OCR the best approach will be Vision API.